# iOS - adding a notification from model to viewcontroller upon successful login (parse ios)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I currently have a ParseManager class setup to handle the signin for a particular user (wanted to avoid tight coupling with a view controller).

I'm trying to figure out a way to notify the view controller that the login has completed successfully that ensures a good design. Here is what I have so far:

ParseManager:

```
- (BOOL) signUpParse:(NSDictionary *)loginDetails
{
   PFUser *newUser = [PFUser user];
   newUser.username = loginDetails[@"username"];
   newUser.password = loginDetails[@"password"];

   [newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if(!error) {
        //i want to let the view controller know that the signup has completed here
     } else {
        NSString *errorString = [error userInfo][@"error"];
    }
}];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you could do this.

### Delegates

One way would be to use delegates. Set up a `ParseManagerDelegate`, for example

```
@protocol ParseManagerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)signInWasSuccessful;

@end
```

And then create a delegate property on `ParseManager`

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<ParseManagerDelegate> delegate;
```

Set this property in your view controller

```
parseManager.delegate = self;
```

You can then call the delegate method like this

```
[newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if(!error) {
        [self.delegate signInWasSuccessful];
     } else {
        NSString *errorString = [error userInfo][@"error"];
    }
}];
```

In your view controller, you would implement the delegate method like this

```
- (void)signInWasSuccessful
{
    //handle log in
}
```

You also have to make your view controller conform to the `ParseManagerDelegate` protocol

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ParseManagerDelegate>
```

### Notifications

Another way would be to use notifications. I wouldn't necessarily recommend this for a log in notification, but you could do it in the following manner.

In your view controller, put the following line somewhere

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleLogInMethod) name:@"LogInNotification" object:nil];
```

And then call that notification like this

```
[newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if(!error) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LogInNotification"];
     } else {
        NSString *errorString = [error userInfo][@"error"];
    }
}];
```

When the user has successfully logged in, `- handleLogInMethod` will be called on the view controller.

### Blocks

A third way to do this would be to use blocks. You could define a new type for your block like this

```
typedef void (^ParseManagerLogInBlock)();
```

Create a property on `ParseManager` for the block

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ParseManagerLogInBlock logInBlock;
```

And then call the block when log in was successful

```
[newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if(!error) {
        self.logInBlock();
     } else {
        NSString *errorString = [error userInfo][@"error"];
    }
}];
```

You would set this block in your view controller

```
parseManager.logInBlock = ^{
    //handle log in here
};
```

Comment: The delegate way is exactly what I'm looking for, clean and elegant! Thanks!

Comment: I just gave the delegates a go but for some reason it's not calling the delegate method implemented in the view controller. I've setup everything as above?

Comment: I accidentally omitted an important part from my answer. In your view controller, be sure that you set the ParseManager's delegate to the view controller: `parseManager.delegate = self;`